# Typescript reflect public / private

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings

I have a hypothetical class

```
class Test {
  @isThisPublic() public test1?: any;
  @isThisPublic() public test2?: any;
}
```

Now, in the `@isThisPublic()` decorator, I want to do different things depending on whether it's a public class field. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript emits additional metadata with [`emitDecoratorMetadata` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) which is available with `reflect-metadata` polyfill for [metadata proposal](https://rbuckton.github.io/reflect-metadata/).

As the proposal states, there can be design-time metadata emitted for property type, method parameter and method return value types.

Visibility is not among emitted metadata, so it's unavailable for decorated members at runtime.

Since both visibility and decorators are specified by a developer, there wouldn't be much benefit from `@isThisPublic()` decorator, because a developer can specify respective decorators (whatever they are for):

```
class Test {
  @Public test1?: any;
  @Private private test2?: any;
}
```

Comment: thanks! It's just somewhat of a hassle to write `@Private private` ... every time, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

As estus mentions in his answer there is no support for this in the compiler.

Adding a decorator specifying the public/private nature of the field is a good option, but  there is always potential in a team that a developer might not be aware of the need for the decoration and forget to add it, or even that the decorator and the modifier might diverge (yes they are right next to each other but sometimes people ignore the obvious), which may lead to bugs down the line.

One way we could add this information ourselves in a type safe way, is to use the fact that `keyof` returns only public fields of the a class. Using this we can build a function that takes an object with only the public fields of the class. The compiler will then enforce that the argument to this function must contain all public fields and only the public fields, and any other field will raise an error.

```
function isPublicMetadata<T>(publicFields: Record<keyof T, true>){
    return publicFields;
}

const publicTestFields = isPublicMetadata<Test>({
    test1: true
    // test2 : true // this is an error
})

class Test {
    test1?: any;
    private test2?: any;
}
```

Comment: this might be the best option for me, just checking for it at runtime. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

My project https://typescript-rtti.org/ makes this possible.

```js
import { reflect } from 'typescript-rtti';

class Test {
  public test1?: any;
  private test2?: any;
  protected test3?: any;
}

expect(reflect(Test).getMethod('test1').isPublic).to.be.true;
expect(reflect(Test).getMethod('test2').isPrivate).to.be.true;
expect(reflect(Test).getMethod('test3').isProtected).to.be.true;
```